# How to update a page content with Navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `Navigator` 2.0 in Flutter and I have pages that have a type and a code to identify themselves.

I have a `Drawer` composed of `Listile`, which can go to pages of different type and code or go to  pages of the same type but different code. **So my problem is navigate between pages of the same type and different code**

This is my stack of pages into the delegate:

```
  List<Page> get _loggedInStack {
    final onLogout = () async {
      await auth.logout();
      splash = true;
      loggedIn = false;
      _clear();
    };
    return [
  if (selectedPageType == "dashboard")
    DashboardPage(
        onPageChange: (String page, String code) {
          selectedPageType = page;
          selectedPageCode = code;
          print(selectedPageCode);
        },
        id: selectedPageCode,
        onLogout: onLogout),
   if (selectedPageType == "chart")
        ChartPage(
            id: selectedPageCode,
            onPageChange: (String page, String code) {
              selectedPageType = page;
              selectedPageCode = code;
              print(selectedPageCode);
            },
            onLogout: onLogout),
       ...
    ];
  }
```

Here is where I go to a selected page:

```
  goToSelectedPage(String type, String config) {
    switch (type) {
      case ('Monitoring'):
        widget.onPageChange('dashboard', config);
        break;
      case ('Charts'):
        widget.onPageChange('chart', config);
        break;
      
      ...
    }
  }
```

Here an example of a Page:

```
class DashboardPage extends Page {
  DashboardPage(
      {required this.onPageChange, required this.onLogout, required this.id})
      : super(key: ValueKey(AppStrings.DASHBOARD_PAGE_KEY));

  final Function(String, String) onPageChange;
  final VoidCallback onLogout;
  final String id;

  @override
  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
        transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
        settings: this,
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
          return DashboardScreen(
            onPageChange: onPageChange,
            onLogout: onLogout,
            id: id,
            key: ValueKey(AppStrings.DASHBOARD_SCREEN_KEY),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

[this is what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylOoz.gif)

So, when I try to change from a page that has the same `selectedPageType` but not the same `selectedPageCode` nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the community!

The problem would seem that in calling the same `selectedPageType` with different  `selectedPageCode` you are using the same key (`AppStrings.DASHBOARD_SCREEN_KEY`). So, try to change the key for each time you call your `DashboardPage` and your `DashboardScreen`, for example adding the `selectedPageCode` :

`key: ValueKey(AppStrings.DASHBOARD_SCREEN_KEY + selectedPageCode)`

By doing this, you shouldn't have any more problems!

Comment: Oh you are right! Thank you so much, you saved my life